# Not able to hide overlay with hide animation in controller

Tags: sencha-touch-2

//Here i am creating overlay on button tap event and loading another view using ContentEl:''. Overlay working fine with animation but i need to hide this overlay with **animation** when user select a particular item in that overlay.

if (!this.overlay)
 {

```
        this.overlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            id:'menuOverlayView',
            modal: true,
            hideOnMaskTap: true,
            centered: true,
            scroll: 'vertical',
            autoDestroy:false,
            floating: true,
            showAnimation: {
                type: 'slide',
                duration: 4000,
                direction:'down'
            },
           hideAnimation: {
                type: 'slide',
                duration: 4000,
                direction:'up'
            },
            contentEl:'menuViewid',
            top: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? '20%' : '20%',
            width: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? 260 : 700,
            height: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? 220 : 600
        });
    }

    this.overlay.show();
```

// And my code to hide this overlay in controller is below .I am accessing panel id and hiding the panel but panel should hide with animation like as i mentioned above **hideAnimation**

```
var overlayView=Ext.getCmp('menuOverlayView');       
 overlayView.setHidden(true);
```

//so what i should do to hide panel with with smooth scrolling up.. i am writingng below sentence but not working giving error

```
 overlayView.hideAnimation({type: 'slide', direction: 'up', duration:1000});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide an overlay `panel`, you need to call `panel's` [`hide()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-hide) method.

```
Ext.getCmp('menuOverlayView').hide();
```

and then try your `hideAnimation` code.

Comment: ya i am able to hide the animation using overlayView.hide() method. But overlay not rendering properly on device what may be the issue. I am adding some image with text like TouchStyle application and creating one menu which is docked on the top of toolbar.On click of item tap i am redirecting to another view but when build native apk whole thing messing up ,content not showing..